# have a variable name from one page to another

Tags: php, html

I have a page which view links from the database.
Now I want that if i pressed on any of these links i will be in another page but still have the variable name i have presses to do some queries on it.

here is the code of the first page:

```
$query = "SELECT Category FROM product WHERE Visible = 0";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
echo "<div style = 'font:40px/60px Arial; color :orange'>All Categories Available :-</div>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $c = $row['Category'];
    echo '<li>'.'<a href ="page2.php?">'.$c.'</a>'.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: Use session variables to keep data from one page to another.

Comment: or else on list links page - append value of variable to the link (as query string) clicking on which you are redirecting to another page

Comment: i don't know how as i want the session value keep only the link that i chosen .

Comment: do you want to perform operation on the basis of $c value....?

Comment: the output of this page is
cars
mobiles 
and every one is a link i want that if i pressed on cars i move to another page but still have the variable cars to make operations on it

Comment: all these values you want at once or individual in second link.

Comment: individual just the one i clicked on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

in your first page:

```
 $query = "SELECT Category FROM product WHERE Visible = 0";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    echo "<div style = 'font:40px/60px Arial; color :orange'>All Categories Available :-</div>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $c = $row['Category'];
        echo '<li>'.'<a href ="page2.php?value=>'.$c.'</a>'.'</li>';  // i put value as variable in redirected page.
    }
```

in your second page like page2.php :

```
if(isset($_GET['value'])){
$url_val = $_GET['value'];
echo $url_val;    // your first page value.
 // do your work
}
```

This will helpful for you.

Comment: i am sorry but there is still a mistake as the url_val is empty ,it has not the any value in it

Comment: check your $c = $row['Category']; field. Is is working properly or not.

Comment: the output is true in the first page as it list all the categories in the database as links but when i click on any one the second page appear but without the echo

Comment: remove " in value field.